# C# Does Each Instance of HttpClient Get it's Own ServicePoint

Tags: c#, .net, http, tcp, httpclient

I have something like the following

```
public async Task PostTest()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("abc.com");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/call", new StringContent("hello world"));
        //do something with response and dispose it.
        //NOTE: server is long running, so dispose is not getting called before sending other remaning requests.
    }
}
```

I in turn call this method from a loop of to send a large number of requests at in quick succession.

Based on what I have read about `HttpClient` it will associate requests to a specific [ServicePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint(v=vs.110).aspx) object, which will have a default [ConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) value of 2. Since all of my requests are to the same uri, only one `ServicePoint` object should be created, and therefore limit me to two maximum concurrent requests (assume pipelining is off).

What I actually see when running this is that if I call my `PostTest()` method at the "same time" **n** times, I see **n** number of requests getting to the server before any response is ever sent back since server's api logic is long running.

Can someone explain why this **example** seems to be exceeding the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) of 2? My best guess is that since I am creating a new `HttpClient` per request the`ServicePointManager` is making a `ServicePoint` object per request, but from what I have read I thought `ServicePointManager` should only create different instances of `ServicePoint` per unique schema and domain, so I am unsure.

NOTE: I do plan on reusing my `HttpClient` instance, but this outcome peaked my curiosity :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is curious, I inspected the `HttpClient` code a little bit, and it looks like each `HttpClient` instantiates an `HttpMessageHandler` per instance. The `HttpMessageHandler` object creates a hash code per instance which gets used to create `ServicePoint` objects, in addition to the schema and domain of the uri defined by the `HttpClient`.

Comment: and FYI here's some guidance for using HttpClient: https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-make-concurrent-requests-with-httpclient/

Answer (score 0):

@cjablonski76 I believe your explanation is wrong. Because the creation of ServicePoint is as follows per the framework code.

```
            sp = new ServicePoint(address)
            {
                ConnectionLimit = DefaultConnectionLimit,
                IdleSince = DateTime.Now,
                Expect100Continue = Expect100Continue,
                UseNagleAlgorithm = UseNagleAlgorithm
            };
            s_servicePointTable[tableKey] = new WeakReference<ServicePoint>(sp);
```

If you see this, there is no usage of hashcode which support your statement.