# .Net Core 3.1 HttpClient does not reuse sockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-core, httpclient

I have the below piece of code which I ran on .Net 4.7.2 and .Net Core but I have got different behavior for each framework

```
public class Program
{


    private HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program example = new Program();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting connections");
        int numberofIterations = 10;
        Task<HttpResponseMessage>[] awaitableTasks = new Task<HttpResponseMessage>[numberofIterations];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofIterations; i++)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
            httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri("https://example.com");
            httpRequestMessage.Method = new HttpMethod("GET");

            awaitableTasks[i] = example.Client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
            //Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Connections done");
        await Task.WhenAll(awaitableTasks);

    }
}
```

With the .Net Core framework, the network traces shows a separate tcp connection for each request while with the.NEt 4.7.2 framework the sockets get reused.

**Network Trace .Net Core**

[image]

**Network Trace .Net 4.7.2**

[image]

Appreciate your thoughts to understand the differences, to explain this behavior and the best way to overcome this issue.

Comment: did you try restsharp?

Comment: I may think of alternatives if I know there is a limitation with the .Net Core  HttpClient. I am just doing basic think which is not sure why not working properly.

Comment: Multiple connections to the same host are allowed (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=net-6.0). You're going to hit that limit, particularly since you haven't read any responses yet.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyLakeman for pointing me out to that, it was the first step toward finding my answer as I was using ServiceEndpointClass with no luck.

Comment: The code is ... unusual. A static method is creating instances of its class to access the new HttpClient instance in each one. The loop fires off 10 requests at exactly the same time too. That means 10 concurrent connections hence 10 concurrent sockets. Without that, the 10 concurrent requests would have to wait to use a single socket one by one

Comment: @LeandroBardelli RestSharp doesn't use its own network stack. It uses HttpClient underneath, either directly or indirectly

Comment: @MohamadHaidar to see whether the sockets are reused, add an outer loop that executes the 10 requests and  awaits them. Or ditch the array and execute *and* await the same request. In both cases you should see that the sockets are reused. You can use just `await client.GetStringAsync(url);` since you don't do anything special with the requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer, the below modification to the code will force my .net core app to not create more than two sockets and reuse them.

```
     var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                MaxConnectionsPerServer = 2
            };

     HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { MaxConnectionsPerServer = 2 };

     var Client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

**Updated Answer**

---

**More Details:**

The .Net Framework 4.x.x HttpClient implementation is built on top of HttpWebRequest and ServicePoint which can be managed by the ServicePointManager. The ServicePointManager has a default connection limit set to 10 for ASP.NET hosted applications and 2 for all others, and that is why in my above example the 2 sockets were opened and reused as the application were prevented to create more than 2 connections(sockets) per service point.

See the references below for a bit more understanding

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=net-6.0#system-net-servicepointmanager-defaultconnectionlimit

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=net-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint?view=net-6.0

[C# Does Each Instance of HttpClient Get it's Own ServicePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144965/c-sharp-does-each-instance-of-httpclient-get-its-own-servicepoint)

In .Net Core, the implementation has been changed multiple times, no longer managed by the ServicePointManager and has no default connection limit. The below article has the full story of the HttpClient Class.

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core

Thanks to @user700390 and @PanagiotisKanavos and @JeremyLakeman for their help and guidance toward getting the answer to this question.

Comment: There's no pooling issue. The code has a bug. What you posted *causes* a (downvotable) issue, forcing an unacceptable limit on HTTP calls. Restricting REST API requests to just 2 per server is unacceptable in any production application

Comment: Can you indicate where is the bug

Comment: I explained the bug in other comments - you're firing 10 *concurrent* requests, which means that 10 concurrent connections are needed until the responses are processed. If you awaited the 10 requests and tried again you'd see that the sockets were reused. As for this answer's bug, I explained that in the first comment - no production app would accept just 2 connections to a service. That was a limitation that made sense for web browsers in the 2000s

Comment: The fact that sockets *are* pooled is why HttpClientFactory is needed - the socket keeps talking to the same machine. If that target goes and gets replaced by another with the same DNS name or IP, the socket won't know. HttpClientFactory *recycles* the cached sockets periodically to ensure they pick up any DNS changes

Comment: Got you, thanks for your comments, they are very helpful. in the production definitely the number will be 1000 but I was a a bit confused from the different behavior between .Net Core and Asp.net 4.x.x and I figured out that his is because of different implementations and because .Net Core does not have a limit for the number of concurrent connections by default. The answer above does not say there is a connection pooling issue but more of how to control the number of concurrent requests and an article to the history of the httpClient and the difference between both implemntations.

Comment: I will update my answer with more details later, if you have other comments, please feel free to comment out, I love to hear from experts like you.

Comment: I have just noticed that I wrote connection pooling issue :(

Comment: @MohamadHaidar Is there any suggestion for dotnet 6/7, we are using this option in dotnet core 6 in aks. We see some connection timed out, not sure what's causing this issue, the destination system doesn't see any requests for those failures and we noticed on new deployment we dont see the time out and it starts after some hours of running

Comment: It could be SNAT port issue, networking issue like TCP handshake failure or .Net CLR queuing issue so you have to corner your issue first and then fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this resource:

[Using HttpClientFactory without dependency injection](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28385)

> If you are on .NET Core - you should use a single HttpClient directly
> and set SocketsHttpHandler.PooledConnectionTimeout here to an
> appropriate value.
>
> If you are on .NET Framework - you should use a single HttpClient and
> use ServicePoint to configure the similar settings.
>
> The good news for anyone interested in connection management is that
> .NET now has reasonable behavior on Linux (as of 2.1 and
> SocketsHttpHandler) but it requires configuration.

More detailed information found in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#alternatives-to-ihttpclientfactory-2](https://Using%20IHttpClientFactory%20in%20a%20DI-enabled%20app%20avoids:%20%20Resource%20exhaustion%20problems%20by%20pooling%20HttpMessageHandler%20instances.%20Stale%20DNS%20problems%20by%20cycling%20HttpMessageHandler%20instances%20at%20regular%20intervals.%20There%20are%20alternative%20ways%20to%20solve%20the%20preceding%20problems%20using%20a%20long-lived%20SocketsHttpHandler%20instance.%20%20Create%20an%20instance%20of%20SocketsHttpHandler%20when%20the%20app%20starts%20and%20use%20it%20for%20the%20life%20of%20the%20app.%20Configure%20PooledConnectionLifetime%20to%20an%20appropriate%20value%20based%20on%20DNS%20refresh%20times.%20Create%20HttpClient%20instances%20using%20new%20HttpClient(handler,%20disposeHandler:%20false)%20as%20needed.%20The%20preceding%20approaches%20solve%20the%20resource%20management%20problems%20that%20IHttpClientFactory%20solves%20in%20a%20similar%20way.%20%20The%20SocketsHttpHandler%20shares%20connections%20across%20HttpClient%20instances.%20This%20sharing%20prevents%20socket%20exhaustion.%20The%20SocketsHttpHandler%20cycles%20connections%20according%20to%20PooledConnectionLifetime%20to%20avoid%20stale%20DNS%20problems.)

> There are alternative ways to solve the preceding problems using a
> long-lived SocketsHttpHandler instance.
>
> Create an instance of SocketsHttpHandler when the app starts and use
> it for the life of the app. Configure PooledConnectionLifetime to an
> appropriate value based on DNS refresh times. Create HttpClient
> instances using new HttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: false) as
> needed. The preceding approaches solve the resource management
> problems that IHttpClientFactory solves in a similar way.
>
> The SocketsHttpHandler shares connections across HttpClient instances.
> This sharing prevents socket exhaustion. The SocketsHttpHandler cycles
> connections according to PooledConnectionLifetime to avoid stale DNS
> problems.

Also possibly relevant (but more focused on DI):

[Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Here are a few relevant excerpts:

> The original and well-known HttpClient class can be easily used, but
> in some cases, it isn't being properly used by many developers.

> Though this class implements IDisposable, declaring and instantiating it
> within a using statement is not preferred because when the HttpClient
> object gets disposed of, the underlying socket is not immediately
> released, which can lead to a socket exhaustion problem. For more
> information about this issue, see the blog post You're using
> HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software.

....

HttpClient lifetimes

> Each time you get an HttpClient object from the IHttpClientFactory, a
> new instance is returned. But each HttpClient uses an
> HttpMessageHandler that's pooled and reused by the IHttpClientFactory
> to reduce resource consumption, as long as the HttpMessageHandler's
> lifetime hasn't expired.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved great answer and fixes my .net core issue but it did not answer how httpclient is different between .Net Core and Asp.Net 4.7.2. I am upvoting your answer I will Answer my question  with more an article that has a bit more details. Thanks again.

Comment: @MohamadHaidar your code is very unusual and the issue could be simply due to that. Have you tried using a *simple* Program class instead? Besides, your code is firing  10 requests at the exact same moment. This means 10 sockets, or all 10 requests waiting for their turn to use a single socket